# Updating a static Python class variable does not update the variable when accessed through another file

Tags: python, class

I have the following code:

test.py

```
class Foo(object):
    index = 0

    @classmethod
    def increase(cls):
        while True:
            cls.index += 1
            print(cls.index)

    @classmethod
    def get_index(cls):
        return cls.index

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo.increase()
```

When I run it, I can see the value of index increasing.

However, while it is running, if in another file I do the following:

test1.py

```
import test

print(test.Foo.get_index())
```

then I get `index=0`. Why is the value of index not being updated?

Comment: if you have 2 distinct python processes running, there is no way you can see the class from another process.

Answer (score 0):

In `test.py`, you have

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

Which prevents any instructions under that condition from being run if the module is imported. If you remove that condition (it will still correctly run as the main module), then you will see the value increment statically on import as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you are calling the function from another class then you must make sure it returns something. But your function *get_index* doesn't return anything.

**Try this**

test.py

```
class Foo(object):
    index = 0

    @classmethod
    def increase(cls):
        while True:
            cls.index += 1
            print cls.index

    @classmethod
    def get_index(cls):
        return Foo.increase()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo.increase()
```

Comment: OP's `Foo.get_index` does return something.

Comment: Yes it does return 0 but that is not what he wants.

Comment: Your implementation of `Foo.get_index` won't return anything. It's returning the return value of another method that would return `None` if not for the infinite loop with no breaking condition. It will eventually terminate with some kind of error, but that is also not what OP is looking for.